# Append view to an already rendered view in afterView/after action in grails filter

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, view, filter

I have to conditionally append view to an already rendered view or when action finishes calling render view. The purpose of this is to show debug information on that page. I do not want to append that in individual page. I tried searching for this and found that it is not directly possible.

The issue http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Why-use-the-afterView-filter-td3390103.html points to similar issue but even this issue is kept unresolved. This post is two years old. Newer version of grails may have solve this issue.

Can any one enlighten me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to append content to buffered GSP output blocks. See this jira for examples:
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6362